# Is Maven just a bunch of Ant scripts?

Tags: java, maven, ant

I know maven is more powerful than ant. But I can't find information on how it's implemented. Is it just a bunch of ant scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, while it's possible to execute Ant tasks in Maven using the [Maven AntRun Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/), Maven is completely independent from Ant.

Like Ant, Maven is implemented in Java and you can configure it with XML.

https://github.com/apache/maven